# Access attributes from CSS

Tags: html, css

I am new to HTML and I am trying some stuff on a page that I'm writing. I'm using Notepad as an Editor, since it was recommended for beginners from [w3schools](http://w3schools.com).
I have a navigation bar, where I intendt to show a dropdownmenu when my mouse is over a menu option (Hover), in this case "Gifts". I am currently learning HTML with CSS, and I do not wish to use any other code yet (like javascript, etc).
Here is my HTML code:

```
    <body>
        <div id="body">
            <div id="header">
            </div>
            <div id="navigation">
                <a href="home.html">Home</a>
                <a id="gifts" href="gifts.html">Gifts</a>
                <div id="giftsDropDownList" hidden="true">
                    <a href="live-gifts.html">Live Gifts</a>
                    <a href="upcoming-gifts.html">Upcoming Gifts</a>
                    <a href="previous-gifts.html">Previous Gifts</a>
                </div>
                <a href="about.html">About</a>
                <a href="register.html">Register</a>
                <a href="log-in.html">Log in</a>
            </div>
            <div id="section">
            </div>
            <div id="footer">
                Visit us on <a href="http://www.facebook.com/WinLOLGifts">Facebook</a> /
                <a href="http://twitter.com/WinLOLGifts">Twitter</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
```

Here is my CSS code:

```
body
{
    background-color: lightgrey;
}
div#body
{
    margin: auto;
    width: 810px;
}
div#header
{
    height: 150px;
    background-color: red;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 5px;
}
div#navigation
{
    float: left;
    height: 500px;
    background-color: #282828;
}
div#navigation a
{
    display: block;
    width: 150px;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    background-color: #282828;
    color: #FFF;
    padding: 5px;
    margin: auto;
}
div#navigation a:hover
{
    background-color: #D96915;
}
div#navigation a:visited
{
    color: #FFF;
}
div#section
{
    background-color: green;
    float: left;
    width: 650px;
    height: 500px;
}
div#footer
{
    width: inherit;
    background-color: brown;
    text-align: center;
    color: #FFF;
}
div#footer a
{
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #FFF;
    padding: 5px;
}
div#footer a:visited
{
    color: #FFF;
}
div#giftsDropDownList a
{
    width: 130px;
}
```

As you can see, I'm using the attribute hidden="true", and I don't know how to access that attribute from CSS.
Any help please?

Comment: You can't change an attribute with CSS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove {hidden = "true"} from html and add this to your css:

```
#giftsDropDownList{
  display:none;
}

#gifts:hover + #giftsDropDownList{
  display:block;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have 2 options:

display block / none

```
a#giftsDropDownList {
    display:none; /* this will hide the dropdownlist */
}
#gifts:hover #giftsDropDownList {
    display:block; /* this will show the dropdownlist */
}
```

Or you could use visibility visible/hidden

```
a#giftsDropDownList {
    visibility:hidden; /* this will hide the dropdownlist */
}
a#gifts:hover #giftsDropDownList {
    visibility:visible; /* this will show the dropdownlist */
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Which option would replicate the functionality of the `hidden=true` attribute ?

Comment: The div "giftsDropDownList" should be visible/hidden only when my mouse pointer is over the a "gifts"